# What is the maximum length a method or function should be?

Tags: methods

A friend from work was arguing with me that it is ok for some methods to be 200 lines long, it can still be easy to understand.

And I was arguing that if you can split big methods, you should.
As a rule of thumb, no method should be, for example, bigger than 30 lines.

I've search a lot of places (at google of course) for a reasonable explanation in favor of each way, but couldn't find anything besides "the code will be more maintainable" or "divide and conquer", but no exact explanation of why.

Could anyone explain to me the concrete reasons as for why big methods are bad (or not)?

Comment: Depends on which language and where it makes sense to break things down - typically shorter methods are better, but they key is to make things readable and encapsulated; there's no hard rules, only guidelines.

Comment: Duplicate of a Programmers.StackExchange question: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/133404/what-is-the-ideal-length-of-a-method

Comment: Also, see http://www.slant.co/topics/2062/~what-is-the-recommended-length-for-a-method (Slant's a Q&A site for subjective questions, so is better suited to answer this)

Comment: I saw that question on stackexchange JohnLBevan and, like I said, they got no concrete explanation. Also, I don't agree that this is a subjective question, I agree that it is not language agnostic, but not subjective. Either smaller or bigger methods will be easier to read and maintain. Maybe it depends on the type of method you are writing, but there is still a better choice for a specific method and language. You can argue that someone might find (for no good reason) a bigger method easier to understand, and, in that case, lets consider the top programmers and decide which is easier to them.

Answer (score 2):

A method, function, or any piece of code is good if someone other than the author can understand it. If your methods start getting long, there is a good chance that some re-factoring or an OOP design principle can be employed to separate it into smaller chunks that have less total responsibility.

(I.e. Single Responsibility Principle)

Writing code is more art than science (sorry Comp. Sci. peeps...its true) I don't know of any compiler that will care if your code is long winded, but if you need to change something later on it will be a royal pain....trust me.

Regardless of what you do, there is always be another programmer with a theory or pattern to apply, but in the end you need to write code that works.  No end user will ever compliment you on how elegant your code is, or on how wonderful you used of a design pattern...all they care about is does it work!

So, where is my advise...

1. Write code with lots of comments
2. Spend time reading about OOP patterns
3. Download and inspect others code often

Comment: Believe me, I trust you =), but I'd like a concrete explanation of why, just so when someone says "this 300 lines method is ok" I can reply "no it is not because of this, this and that".

Comment: There will never be a concrete number of lines or reason.  The answer will always be...it depends.  Arbitrary "rules of thumb", like 300 lines, or 30 lines, makes absolutely no sense.  If you study design patterns and principles, you will be better aware of when (and how) to re-factor your code to incorporate new user requirements.  If a 300 line method works, there may not be a valid reason to change it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a method of 200 lines, and you give this code to someone else, that person might want to change it, but before he can do that he will have to go through 200 lines before he understands what to edit. It's just not efficient because it's not easily readable.

In practice, a 200 line method can always be split up in multiple methods (divide and conquer as you call it). The advantage of this, is that these methods can be re-used, and your method becomes more readable. Now if you need to edit that piece of code, you only need to edit it once, instead of having to copy your code twice.

That said, I think a maximum of 30 lines for a method is quite appropiate. But as a rule of thumb you should always ask yourself if parts of your method could be re-used, split up for readability purposes, or if you can use other methods to make your code smaller and therefore more readable. By having parameters in your methods you can make your method more flexible which is also a good thing, because you can re-use it in other methods.

Comment: What if I say (as I have heard from my friend at work) that even with those 200 lines, it is really fast to understand them, because, for example, that method is only setting some initialization variables? As for reusability, lets say that even if I split the 200 lines method in smaller ones, I'd never have to reuse the small ones, that first method is the only place I'll ever call the small methods I just created.

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz Then you should still split up the method in smaller ones for readability purposes, which results in better maintainable code. Say you have a console application. In practice it often happens that the entry point method (i.e. main method) gets big pretty quickly. Instead of copy pasting the code that asks the user for his credentials, you should instead just write a method that keeps asking for user input, until the user enters the correct credentials.

Comment: You might not re-use this method, but it might happen that in the future you want to add functionality that makes it possible for the user to log out, and then you'll have to ask his credentials later on. You can then just call the method and re-use it. Thus, your code is more maintainable. If you plan on projects with 200 initialization variables you should really think about using OOP (like Phil said) and dynamic arrays (arrays that don't need a size specified).

Comment: I hope you understand now, that methods are great for reusability and readability. Modularity is also a key factor, but you will learn about this as you learn about OOP. That said, don't spin your head around this topic too much if it confuses you. It will come natural to you as you get more and more experienced. If you really want to know for certain, you could read a good book about code management.

Comment: The thing is, I already know =). I just don't know how to explain it to others. Like I said, I have an experienced friend who disagrees with you, basically he says that a code is sometimes more readable if it is not split in multiple methods (assuming we don't need reusability). So basically, why are smaller method easier to read (I know they are, I just don't know how to prove it)?

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz http://www.brandautopsy.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/einstein_2012.jpg Usually, the smaller a method is, the less complex it gets. Therefore it's easier to read. The key thing you want in your method is readability. Whether a method should be split up in multiple methods is dependent on the scenario. If it's easy to understand and you can't re-use the code, then don't change a thing.